# Transform rotateX(40deg) when hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to make a panel, that when hovered over, tilts slightly. I figured I should use JQuery since I know that better then advanced CSS animation. I have tried a lot of things but it won't work. The code below is what I currently have. I would appreciate it, if you told me what I am doing wrong, or if it is not possible to do in JQuery, tell me how I can do it.

https://jsfiddle.net/tf5xd7px/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('proj1').hover(function() {
    $('proj1').animate({
      transform: 'rotateX(40deg)'
    }, 'slow');
  });
});
```

```css
#proj1 {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/FddIcrz.png');
  background-position: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  /*position:relative;
      bottom:300px;*/
  left: 150px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px gray;
  /*-webkit-transition: rotateX 4s;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='projects'>
  <div id='proj1'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: `-webkit-transition: rotateX 4s;` won’t work because `rotateX` isn’t a CSS property of its own; it’s actually `transform`. When doing 3D stuff like tilting you need to use [`perspective`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/perspective). And then you can use CSS `:hover` without jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
transform: 'rotateX(40deg)'
```

is not an animatable property (jquery animation works with basic numbers). You also had a few errors with the jsfiddle setup that was preventing this from running (like not turning on jquery and only using proj1 as your jquery selectors instead of #proj1).

If you're looking to turn it and turn it back on hover-out, use

```
#proj1:hover {
  transform: rotateX(40deg);
}
```

If you want it to rotate and stay there, you can add a class on hover, like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/tf5xd7px/3/

**Update**

It looks like you're looking for a 3d card flip style, not a flat rotation. Add perspective to your container like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/tf5xd7px/4/

Answer (score -1):

No JavaScript needed for this. This simple CSS style work (you should add the prefixes):

```
#proj1:hover {
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}
```

Check the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/tf5xd7px/2/

Comment: I see what you did there, but when I said tilt slightly, I mean gradually and in a 3D way. kinda like this > http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php

Comment: `rotateX` is not the same as `rotate` and it needs an extra property `perspective`.